# dojox/widget/Wizard height keeps increasing when window is resized

Tags: layout, dojo

I'm finding that even with a very basic setup, my dojox/widget/Wizard keeps increasing in height every time you resize the window.

```
  <div data-dojo-type="dojox/widget/Wizard">
    <div data-dojo-type="dojox/widget/WizardPane">
      <h1>This is pane 1</h1>
      <div>
        <p>This is content for pane 1</p>
        <ul><li>foo</li><li>foo2</li><li>foo</li></ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

CodePen example: https://codepen.io/neekfenwick/pen/WXgJrm

with no custom CSS affecting it, lays out OK when the window loads, but then resizing the window, vertically or horizontally, makes the wizard increase in height by about 39px each time.

I am not sure if it is CSS related or something in the Javascript sizing logic.  I had started with a flexbox layout inside the `WizardPane` and thought this was confusing the `_ContentPaneResizeMixin` logic somehow, but taking this out still shows the bad behaviour.

Some debugging shows that `_LayoutWidget` line:

```
mb = lang.mixin(domGeometry.getMarginBox(node), mb);    // just use domGeometry.marginBox() to fill in missing values
```

is coming up with a `mb.h` that is taller each time the window resizes, which is then given to `_ContentPaneResizeMixin` as the new height to set itself to.

Does not seem related to https://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/5849.

Is this a known bug in, `_LayoutWidget`, `_ContentPaneResizeMixin` or `Wizard`, and how should we fix or workaround it?

Comment: Workaround: https://codepen.io/neekfenwick/pen/rYZvQy - remove `margin-bottom:39px`; I see the Wizard.css contains a rule `.dojoxWizardContainer > * { margin-bottom:39px; }` and it seems the Wizard's layout code is calculating its content height plus this 39px and setting that as the new height of the WizardPane.  Is this a side effect of the change a few Dojo versions back, when `StackContainer` children had a new intermediary div with `role="tabpanel"` introduced, and Wizard has not had its CSS updated to take account of the change to what `.dojoxWizardContainer > *` refers to?

Comment: yep @Neek seem's this workaround your problem

Comment: I think posting this comment as an answer would be better , and helpfull for others facing same issue :)

Comment: Thanks @bRIMOs, I was hoping for someone with more knowledge of the dijit changes over the years to provide official solution or advice.  My comment above may be better as an Edit to the original question.  I am close to giving up entirely on Wizard, or any dijit layout, and creating my own solution, because the layout logic is so impenetrable.  My second pane has an `<svg>` node (dojox.gfx) and some variable content, and I can't get the wizard to size itself appropriately.

Comment: FYI I seem to have got a Wizard to resize itself according to its content: https://codepen.io/neekfenwick/pen/xPyWpv  .. I saw on the Wizard test page http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/nightly/dojotoolkit/dojox/widget/tests/test_Wizard.html all examples set the Wizard's height via CSS and let its contents lay themselves out, so my solution is to measure the inner content, set the `Wizard`'s height, and tell it to resize (thus laying out its children, the `WizardPane`s).  I think I can go forward with this solution.

Comment: yeah , I used Dojox wizard in one of my project , there were too many problem in resizing ... , So I did it programmaticly as you described in your codepen ,  since it's in dojoX (experimental package )  means not validated widgets  hence those problem , 
Cheers